# facing problem in sharing link to the social platform in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, deeplink

**Summery -:** 
I am working on ionic application where I am trying to share a page of ionic Application on android platform ,  via deepLink

**Problem -: When I am sharing the link of the page , exapmle on watsapp -:
          link dosen't sent as a link but it is sent as text.**

**Details**

Link ->  **http://ionicapp://example.com/second** ,

app.component ts file 
deepLink

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public deeplinks: Deeplinks ,   public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
   // this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    platform.ready().then(() => {
     statusBar.styleDefault();
     splashScreen.hide();

     this.deeplinks.route({
           '/' : {},
           '/second': { 'ThirdPage' : true }    }).subscribe((match) => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(match)) ; alert('matched');
     } , (noMatch) => {alert(JSON.stringify(noMatch)); alert('failed') })
     });

  }
}
```

component.ts for sharing on watsapp

```
 shareViaWhatsapp(){
    alert('hello');
  this.socialShare
  .shareViaWhatsApp("https://ionicapp://example.com/second",null,"https://ionicapp://example.com/second")
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Error');
  });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you pass only url like :  this.socialShare.shareViaWhatsApp(null,null,"https://ionicapp://example.com/second")

Comment: I did that , but it still shows text but not link

Comment: I checked. and this is how whats app works. You might have not checked but your code works fine with IOS but not with android. for whatsapp on ios, "https://ionicapp://example.com/second" is a valid URL but not for whatsapp on android. you can check this on both platform to see difference.